# Можно ли Android Studio в само название строкового ресурса вставить переменную?

Tags: java, android, строки

Здравствуйте! Суть в чем

есть в string.xml следующий код

```
<string-array name="stroka_1">
    <item>Текст1</item>
    <item>Текст2</item>
    <item>Текст3</item>
</string-array>       
<string-array name="stroka_2">
    <item>Текст11</item>
    <item>Текст22</item>
    <item>Текст33</item>
</string-array>
```

В Активити получаю строковые ресурсы

```
String[] Stroki= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stroka_2);
```

Есть ли такая возможность в java, в конце вместо 2 поставить переменную

Пример:

```
String str = "1";
String[] Stroki= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stroka_+str);
```

Код естественно показывает ошибку, но идея я думаю понятна.

Что бы не прописывать вручную все стринги

```
R.array.stroka_1
R.array.stroka_2
R.array.stroka_3
R.array.stroka_4
```

А просто взять вместо этих цифр вставить переменную

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
int i = 1;
String name = "stroka_"+ i;

int holderint = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "array",
                this.getPackageName());
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(holderint);
```

Только нужно заключить это в цикл, чтобы пробежаться по всем i.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565108/android-referencing-string-array-using-another-string-with-getidentifier-and)

Comment: Спасибо дружище!!! Все работает

Comment: @Artsait Не за что :)  Если вам не трудно, отметьте, пожалуйста, мой ответ как верный, нажав галку слева от него.

Answer (score 5):

Используй форматирование строк (как в C). Например:

```
 <string name="my_str">Первая переменная:%1$d вторая переменная: %2$d</string>
```

Далее в коде

```
 String str = String.format(getString(R.string.my_str), 1, 123);
 textView.setText(str);
```

Получится: **Первая переменная:1 вторая переменная: 123**

Comment: Речь идет не о подстановке значений в выводимую строку, а о динамическом формировании идентификатора строки (R.string.text1, R.string.text2 и тд. к примеру).